# How to display rss feed from wordpress site in Xcode 4.3.2 iOS 5 SDK for iPhone?

Tags: xcode, wordpress, ios5, rss

I've viewed tutorials from: http://www.raywenderlich.com/ and similar articles.

I've downloaded and viewed github:
https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWFeedParser

I've yet to find a simple way to do the following:

Show the last 10 articles (via rss feed) of one specific website in a tableview (with or without image not important right now).
When user clicks on a tableview cell, they will see the post with pictures and main body content.

Understand that I'm still an amateur iOS 5 dev and that I have yet to use ANY 3rd party libraries (from github, etc.), therefore any answers that might direct me to simple tutorials, or how to easily implement a 3rd party library will be helpful. Meanwhile I will continue to research and understand what I have found thus far in addition to github. But I figured I would post this question in the meantime. Thanks for any support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! Haven't tried yet, but this tutorial is for iOS 5.1 Xcode 4.3.2. Took me a few days to find what I was looking for lol.
http://www.kieranmcgrady.com/blog/2012/4/25/tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-rss-reader-for-ios.html

Comment: Here is another simple tutorial: http://gigaom.com/2008/08/04/tutorial-build-a-simple-rss-reader-for-iphone/

Comment: Kieran seems to have some code for this tutorial at GitHub (https://github.com/KieranMcGrady/RSSReader), but no tutorial text.